# Hotspot creates two coloured lines on left and right side on "mouse down"

Tags: css

I have an image of text that I have hotspotted so when I hover the mouse over a specific word it changes the image to give the effect of an arrow appearing next to the word.

[image]

This works fine but the problem is that on "mouse down" the hotspot adds two lines either side of itself like so:

[image]

The coloured lines that are being created by the hotspot are the same colour as the links on my webpage so I know it is my css creating the problem but I'm not sure how.

CSS:

```
a:link {
    color: #C24B0C;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: #C24B0C;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    color: #C24B0C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    color: #fdbc2c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="images/toplinks.png" width="500" height="22" border="0" usemap="#Map" id="Image1" />

<map name="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="361,-6,458,25" href="contract.html" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','images/toplinks3.png',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
  <area shape="rect" coords="252,-7,338,23" href="quote.html" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','images/toplinks2.png',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
</map>
```

[ADDED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/82TUw/)
: If you hover over the placeholder image, you will find the hotspot. click and hold mouse down and you will see the error

Just found out it only happens in Chrome also.

Comment: make sure you haven't done any css related to a in this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outline`; [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/82TUw/2/)

```css
area {
    outline : none !important;
}
```

Comment: Nope, removing all underlines doesn't work. I've added a Fiddle to my original post now so you can see the problem.

Comment: I've changed my answer

Comment: Brilliant! this one was driving me crazy